# Entity Framework Code First 4.1 IIS worker process memory footprint grows continually

Tags: memory-leaks, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a small website (MVC 3) that does some basic data collection.  I have some seemingly random timeouts and upon investigation I have noticed that whenever a page that contains CRUD operations is executed, the IIS worker process memory usage grows a little bit but never reduces.

The site uses EF Code First.  This is my first attempt at EFCF so I wouldn't be surprised if I created a problem.  Any suggestion on what I should check or best practices for handling the objects to ensure that they are properly disposed of when the view completes would be greatly appreciated.

I can provide sample code if necessary.

Comment: are you holding context or entities in session or in statics?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your code is not holding on to a reference of your DBContext.  Your DBcontext instance should be as short lived as possible. Also, check to see if you have disabled object tracking.  If object tracking is enabled and you are keeping an instance of your DBContext as a session/application/static variable. then your memory usage will grow.

To disable object tracking construct your queries in the following manner

from e in mycontext.Entities.**AsNoTracking()**
where (condition)
select e

This will stop the dbcontext from caching your entities.